# stack unwinding using unwind.h

Tags: gcc, stack, trace

I want to do stack unwinding using gcc. I can not find an example code that shows me how to do this.

I tried to follow the instructions [from this site](http://blog.bigpixel.ro/2010/09/stack-unwinding-stack-trace-with-gcc/), but i realised that the `unwind.h` that my gcc is using is different. for example instead of `unw_word_t` I have `_Unwind_Word`. I don't know what I should use instead of `unw_getcontext()` and `unw_init_local()`.

my `unwind.h` is similar to http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/gcc/gcc-5482/gcc/unwind.h

can anyone please give me a link to an example code to use this library?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=c+unwind

Answer (score 0):

The example which you are trying to use is for "libunwind", but yours header belongs to "libcorkscrew".
If you need a good example about how to use "your unwind" library you can look at Android Open Source project, they implemented class CallStack which realizes all needed functionality for different architectures.
Exactly for your case I would recommend you look at file:

YOUR_PROJECT_FOLDER/system/core/libcorkscrew/backtrace.c

In that file, for example, function "unwind_backtrace" uses "_Unwind_Backtrace" from the libcorkscrew library. Using that file you can easily adapt your example.